# How to get a contract storage data or call a "get" entrypoint from another contract in smartPy?

Tags: smartpy, storage

I want to interact with the FA12.py smart contract (https://smartpy.io/demo/index.html?template=FA1.2.py) and get the balance of a user, from another smart contract.

the FA12 function that I tried to call  :

```
@sp.entry_point 
def getBalance(self, params): 
    sp.transfer(
        sp.as_nat(self.data.balances[params.arg.owner].balance),
        sp.tez(0), 
        sp.contract(sp.TNat, params.target).open_some()
    )
```

What I tried to do from another contract:

```
@sp.entry_point
def getFA12Balance(self, params):
    assertTrasnferRecord = sp.TRecord(arg = sp.TRecord(owner = params.owner), target = params.address)
    entryPointName = "getBalance"
    c = sp.contract(
        t = sp.TNat,
        address = self.data.FA12Address,
        entry_point = entryPointName
    ).open_some()

    sp.transfer(assertTrasnferRecord, sp.mutez(0), c)
```

The answer I get :

```
Error: Error in Scenario 
Literal format error: (record(record((arg(record((owner(attr(params 186)owner 187)))None))(target(attr(params 186)address 187)))None))
```

**** EDIT ****

after fixing the format error based on FFF answer:

```
def getBalance(self, params):
    assertTrasnferRecord = sp.record(arg = sp.record(owner = params.owner), target = params.address)
    entryPointName = "getBalance"
    c = sp.contract(
        t = sp.TRecord(arg = sp.TRecord(owner = sp.TAddress), target = sp.TAddress),
        address = self.data.FA12Address,
        entry_point = entryPointName
    ).open_some()

    call(assertTrasnferRecord, c)
```

I'm still have an error when testing the function with smartpy as follows :

```
c2.getBalance(owner = alice.address, address = c2.address).run(sender = admin)
```

Error text :

```
Error: Error in Scenario
Unexpected error in transaction, please use .run(valid=False, ..)
ChannelNotFound: 'default'
default (18 : sp.TNat)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    assertTrasnferRecord = sp.TRecord(arg = sp.TRecord(owner = params.owner), target = params.address)
```

You're building a type `sp.TRecord` and put a value inside `params.owner`.
This is not well built which leads to a `Literal format error`.

Instead of using `sp.TRecord`, you should try `sp.record` to build an expression (not a type).

Comment: Thank you @FFF ! That fixed the previous error, but I'm still have another one, as described in the issue edit

Answer (score 1):

In addition to FFF answer the type of your entry point is not “sp.TNat” so i expect after you fixed the first error he showed you will get another typing error.

When you call “open_some” you are expected to provide full specification of the entry point argument type. Please see

https://www.smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_contract_and_address

Comment: Thank you ! That fixed the first error, but I'm still have another one..

Comment: @Ahmed it’s unclear from your question edit if your problem is solved or not. Can you clarify if you still have an error after the suggested edits you made ?

Comment: I'm still have an error: detrails are in the issue edit